# LogitBoost requires the base estimator to be a regressor

Tags: python, classification, ensemble-learning, boosting

I have a dataset that all the values for each feature are numeric, even the class/label column. In boosting algorithms implemented in python (like logitboost, adaboost, gradientboosting), other than the preset base estimators (or weak learners, model that iterates through our data) we can specify a classification algorithm, like SVC from SVM, like naive bayes and so on. (some algorithms/packages like xgboost and catboost which are implemented in python, can't accept any other base estimator other than the ones implemented within the package... maybe a implementation preference?)

With this introduction, i present my problem. This code here doesn't work and gives this error: `LogitBoost requires the base estimator to be a regressor.`

```
for j in range(1, 21):
for i in range(1, 11):
    X_train = pd.read_csv('{}-train{}-1.csv'.format(j, i))
    y_train = pd.read_csv('{}-train{}-2.csv'.format(j, i))
    X_test = pd.read_csv('{}-test{}-1.csv'.format(j, i))
    y_test = pd.read_csv('{}-test{}-2.csv'.format(j, i))
    model = logitboost.LogitBoost(base_estimator = svm.SVC())
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_predict = model.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict)
    print('Accuracy for dataset {}, segment {} is: '.format(j, i), accuracy)
    print('Confusion Matrix for Datatset {}, segment {} is: '.format(j, i))
    print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_predict))
```

Please, don't mind the indention. It shows wrong here, but, it is correct on idle. I apologize for that.

The line:

```
model = logitboost.LogitBoost(base_estimator = svm.SVC())
```

doesn't work with SVC, which it should, because logitboost is a classification algorithm. But, it does work with SVR (support vector regression) which is not what i want. Can anyone explain why that happens and how i can solve it? I need to use same base estimators for each algorithm for the sake of fairness in comparison...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how LogitBoost (and GBM) works.  Each additional weak learner is fitting to the *residual*, and so needs to be a regressor.  (The initial prediction in LogitBoost seems to just be 0.5 for all samples. I think other implementations may take the average response instead.)

From the [documentation](https://logitboost.readthedocs.io/logitboost.html):

> `base_estimator:object, optional`
>   The base estimator from which the
>   LogitBoost classifier is built. This should be a *regressor*. If no
>   `base_estimator` is specified, a decision stump is used.

Adaboost is different, in that it alters the *weights* of the misclassified samples, but each new weak learner is still fitting to the original data, and so are classifiers.

Comment: Thank you for your response.